# What does *[, keyword_arg = value] do in Python keyword only function definition?

Tags: python-3.x, keyword-argument

Consider this:

```
help(min)
```

which gives:

```
Help on built-in function min in module builtins:    

min(...)
    min(iterable, *[, default=obj, key=func]) -> value
    min(arg1, arg2, *args, *[, key=func]) -> value
    
    With a single iterable argument, return its smallest item. The
    default keyword-only argument specifies an object to return if
    the provided iterable is empty.
    With two or more arguments, return the smallest argument.
```

My question is what is the difference between:

```
min(iterable, *[, default=obj, key=func]) -> value
```

and

```
min(iterable, *, default=obj, key=func) -> value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python documentation/help derives from [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) to describe grammar. A pair of `[` `]` means "optional" in EBNF and the Python documentation; for terseness, common symbols like `(` `)` and names are not quoted in the documentation even though this has different meaning in EBNF.
The `*` and `,` are derived from Python's [call syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls). `*` means "end of positional parameters".

For the concrete example of

```py
min(iterable, *[, default=obj, key=func]) -> value
```

this means `default` and `key` are optional keyword-only parameters.

Answer (score 1):

This is not Python syntax, it is just used in the help text to show that those arguments are optional.